# Regex of phone number - how to make sure the user won't put +-*+-*+-*+-*?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio

I want to allow the user to enter only patterns like:

> +9720545455454
>
> 056565656345
>
> 03-43434344
>
> 0546-4234234
>
> *9090
>
> +97203-0656534

Meaning, I don't want to allow the user to gibberish everything together, like:

> +954-4343+3232*4343+-
>
> +-4343-+5454+9323+234

How can I fixed this pattern

```
public static bool IsPhoneNumberCorrect(string phoneNumber)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber, @"^[0-9*+-]+$");
}
```

for that purpose?

Comment: do you allow for `+` signs inside the phone number or only at the beginning?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Only at the beginning .

Comment: and only one hyphen is allowed? is `972-3-5551234` allowed?

Comment: Any reason you're not using something like [GitHub: libphonenumber](https://github.com/erezak/libphonenumber-csharp) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: "patterns like <blah>" is *not* a specification. You need to be more specific in what validity means here. That means listing the rules explicitly rather than having us trying to figure them out from a few samples.

Comment: Many countries use spaces rather than hyphens. Additionally, area codes are often in parentheses. E.g. in the UK this is normal: `+44 (1632) 960 239`

Comment: @Ron: Nobody objects to people that are  learning.  Your phrasing of the question showed no evidence that you had read such docs.  If you had complained about a specific issue that you didn't understand, that would have been one issue.  Otherwise this is "gimme the codez".

Comment: Rather than restrict what the user may type, you want to strip out any special characters other than the initial +, then format the number to the traditional format of the country. At the very least you should have a list of valid country codes so e.g. America/Canada `+1 555123456`, UK: `+44 1632960239` and so on. List of valid country codes are on Wikipedia. Portugal: `+351 000000000` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not care about digit group length, you can allow `+` or `*` only at the beginning, and then match initial digits and then optional groups of hyphen+digits:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumber, @"^[+*]?\d+(?:-\d+)*$");
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%2B%2A%5D%3F%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A-%5Cd%2B)%2A%5Cr%3F%24&i=%2B9720545455454%0D%0A056565656345%0D%0A03-43434344%0D%0A0546-4234234%0D%0A%2A9090%0D%0A%2B97203-0656534&o=m)

Note you can limit the number of hyphen+digit with a quantifier. Say, there can be none or 1:

```
^[+*]?\d+(?:-\d+)?$"
                 ^
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B%2B*%5D%3F%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A-%5Cd%2B)%7B0%2C1%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=%2B9720545455454%0D%0A056565656345%0D%0A03-43434344%0D%0A0546-4234234%0D%0A*9090%0D%0A%2B97203-0656534&o=m)

And in case there can be more than 1, use a limiting quantifier:

```
^[+*]?\d+(?:-\d+){0,3}$"
                 ^^^^^
```

Here, `{0,3}` means 0, 1, 2 or 3 repetitions of the hyphen+digits group.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!(.*\+){2})(?!(.*-){2})(?!(.*\*){2})[0-9*+-]+$
```

YOu can use `lookaheads` to make sure `special characters` appear only `once`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/1

Answer (score 0):

What you first need to do is identify what exactly the pattern is. This doesn't need to be in code. In you example, I see a leading character, followed by a first number group, followed by an optional dash and second number group. The leading character can be +, * or 0. The number groups are one digit between 1 and 9 followed by one or more digits 0 to 9. Translating each element gives:

Leader: [+*0]

Dash: -

Number group: [1-9][0-9]+

Throwing everything together you get

```
[\+\*0][1-9][0-9]+(-[1-9][0-9]+)?
```

Some groups may have minimum and maximum lengths, you can still work that in changing + to {min, max}.